# php CURL авторизация

Tags: php, php-curl

Почему не проходит CURL авторизация на сайте `https://kabinet_dot_3ton_dot_eu`?

вот такая функция

```
function login($url,$login,$pass){
   $ch = curl_init();
   if(strtolower((substr($url,0,5))=='https')) { // если соединяемся с https
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   // откуда пришли на эту страницу
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   // cURL будет выводить подробные сообщения о всех производимых действиях
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"wizard[username]=".$login."&wizard[password]=".$pass);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   //сохранять полученные COOKIE в файл
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
   $result=curl_exec($ch);

   // Убеждаемся что произошло перенаправление после авторизации
   if(strpos($result,"Location: gsm-platby-sim.html")===false) die('Login incorrect');

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}

$url="https___centrum_dot_3ton_dot_eu";
$login="asd";
$pass="asd";

echo login($url,$login,$pass);
```

Вместо букв в пароле подставить нужно цифры

Сразу скажу что код невозможно на сайте поменять.

Comment: А `curl_error($ch);` что возвращает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот у меня все получилось  пользуйся готовым решением)))

```
<?php
function login($url,$login,$pass){
   $ch = curl_init();
   if(strtolower((substr($url,0,5))=='https')) { // если соединяемся с https
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   // откуда пришли на эту страницу
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   // cURL будет выводить подробные сообщения о всех производимых действиях
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"odeslano=true&wizard[username]=".$login."&wizard[password]=".$pass);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
   //сохранять полученные COOKIE в файл
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie_kabinet.3ton.eu.txt');
   $result=curl_exec($ch);

   // Убеждаемся что произошло перенаправление после авторизации
   if(strpos($result,"Location: ./main-page.html")===false) die('Login incorrect');

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}

$url="https://kabinet.3ton.eu/uvod";
$login="asd";
$pass="asd";

echo login($url,$login,$pass);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все пробежало. капец. можете немного описать последовательность действий, хоть немного? думаю будет полезно и другим.