# Подулючться к странице Samsung для проверки imei/sn

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Есть такая страница Samsung - https://www.samsung.com/ph/support/your-service/register-product
Необходимо зайти либо через Google-аккаунт, либо через аккаунт Самсунга
Для подключения к странице использую это:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.samsung.com/ph/support/your-service/getModelInfoAjax");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "sn_imei=".$imei_sn."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);



$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";

$headers[] = "Accept-Language: ru,pl-PL;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6";
$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$headers[] = "Content-Length: 23";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Cookie: WMONID=VK-3ay2NevA; RT='z=1&dm…ntry_codes=ph; device_type=pc";
$headers[] = "Origin: https://www.samsung.com";
$headers[] = "Referer: https://www.samsung.com/ph/support/your-service/register-product";

$headers[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpReques";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Для тестов можете использовать этот imei: 352979100330876

В результате получаю ответ что нужно зарегистрироваться. Каким образом можно пройти эту авторизацию для проверки imei через скрипт?

Comment: Нужно зарегистрироваться и передавать авторизационные данные на эту страницу.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov подскажи, как это сделать через curl?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Может подскажешь как решить проблему?)

Comment: то же самое, курлом передать логин/пароль и сохранить авторизационные куки, потом с этими куками чекай имей.

Comment: последний хедер X-Requested-With неправильно передал

Comment: @Jean-Claude а на какую страницу логи и пароль передать?

Comment: sign in - там же есть кнопка

Comment: @Jean-Claude не смог разобраться :( очень нужна ваша помощь :(

Comment: а что, api  у них нет?

Comment: @Jean-Claude нету:(

Comment: вон пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459874/php-curl-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: еще https://xdan.ru/avtorizacija-na-sajte-pri-pomoshhi-curl-php.html

Comment: @Jean-Claude проблема в том, что пароль явно не передать, кодировка происходит пароля

Comment: ну так закодируй, если это делает js, в исходном коде страницы подсмотри алгоритм

Comment: @Jean-Claude а если подключиться через Гугл аккаунт?